# How to programmatically interact with Hashtags.org?

Tags: api, twitter

I've recently come across this website. Now, is there any way I can actually communicate with this service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated on the [Twitter Wiki](http://twitter.pbworks.com/Hashtags),

> Hashtags are a community-driven
>   convention

...so I don't know if there's a specific API yet for that. But, as they are per-se, regular parts of tweets, you can very well use Twitter API to search and organize posts, people and topics, based on them.

In the *Further Reading* section of Twitter Wiki, you'll find numerous resources related to this topic, and perhaps even some steps that will guide you more than I can.

Comment: Great! Thanks... So I found an API that allows searching but need to find how to search using a hashtag and perhaps find a way to get related hashtags...

Comment: Hashtags.org aggregates them and generates statistics - most popular, etc. Not possible via the Twitter API easily.

Comment: Ok one problem solved: For searching using hashtags (up to 16 characters): http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=%23haiku

Comment: This does not give you all the results of haiku right? It is only showing you 15 results? Or is there any way that you figured out to get all the results for that hashtag?

Answer (score 1):

They don't appear to have an API. You can screen scrape, but they may not be a fan of that, and changes to their HTML could break your scripts.

Have you tried contacting them?

Comment: Yes. I've mailed them. I'll update the post once I hear a reply. I don't really want to screen scrape if they don't officially allow that... Thanks anyways...